# Using H2 server mode for Grails integration tests

Tags: grails, groovy, h2

I want to try user H2 db  in server  mode for my grails integration tests, but there is a problem: `H2GrailsPlugin: Started TCP Server - args: -tcp,-tcpPort,8043
ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost:8043"`

Now I use grails h2 plugin, for running H2 server with next configuration in my Config.groovy:

```
plugins {
h2 {
    tcpserver {tcpPort = 8043;}
}
}
```

This is my DataSourse:

```
    test {
    dataSource_one {
        pooled = true
        driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
        username = "sa"
        password = ""

        dbCreate = "update"
        //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        url = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8043/testDb"
    }
```

Also I tried direct run of the Server in my Bootstrap.groovy:

```
import grails.util.Environment
import org.h2.tools.Server

class BootStrap {

    Server server
def init = { servletContext ->

    println "INIT"

    if(Environment.current == Environment.TEST){
        server = Server.createTcpServer('-tcpPort', '8043').start()
    }
}
def destroy = {
    server.stop()
}
}
```

but this code wasn't executed cause of exception was thrown before . It would be great, if someone help me with this issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to use h2 on 8043? Did you test connection if h2 is available on 8043. I would recommend first try removing

plugins {
h2 {
    tcpserver {tcpPort = 8043;}
}
} and run it normally with default setup that grails comes with

Comment: I need multiple connections functionality and as I know only server mode provides it, not embedded which comes by default.